# Upload videos to youtube from asp.net app without API

Tags: c#, youtube-api, webservices-client, youtube-channels, youtube.net-api

I just wanted to know

It is simple to upload videos to youtube in c# but i want to do that without using their API. I am going to create a webpart for office365, so i can't use any external dlls. Only the .NET framework's assembly i can use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Incase you want to upload to youtube you should use their apis, otherwise there is no way you can upload on to youtube, incase your problem is install APIs on office365 cloud, then you can look for Webservices to upload to Youtube, in web services case you have no dlls to register on the cloud.

Answer (score 0):

No not simple, you have to create something that does what their API does. You do not have to build all functionality, only what you need. But still; not easy.